# How to block outgoing emails to a single recipient in my contacts? (Outlook 2007)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, blocking

Just like the question asks, how can I do this?

It's my fist time Superuser so please if I'm doing something wrong in this question tell me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The only way I know is to make sure they're not in any of the "send to" fields. From your question I suspect it is not yourself but someone else who is sending to that address.

Comment: Remove the email address from the contact details

Answer (score 0):

There is to my knowledge no way of doing this. You would actually have to do this from the mail provider itself with filters if provided.